# Defining new types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, haskell-platform

I am pretty new to Haskell, and I was wondering if one can define new types that are defined by lists of other types. For example, I assume a string is defined as a list of characters, so can I define a vector as a list of force values (in this case floating point values)?

If so, how can I declare and use this?

`data Vector = Vector [Float]`

Is this enough to define the new type and the constructor for it? Can I simply call
`x = Vector [2.4,2.5,2.7]` for example?

I'm using ghci, if that makes any difference

Comment: Have you tried it? If you do, you should find the answer is "yes". Beyond that, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Note that `String` is different in that that's defined as a *type alias* in the standard library (Prelude), rather than a different type defined with `data` or `newtype`. So a String is simply the same thing as a `[Char]`, a list of characters (although it has special syntax that other list types don't share). If you wanted to do this for your `Vector` type you would simply put `type Vector = [Float]` and then `x = [2.4, 2.5, 2.7]` is of type `Vector`. (As well as being of type `[Float]`, as those two names would denote the same type.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes - `data TypeName = TypeConstructor Type1 Type2 ... TypeN` just creates a function `TypeConstructor :: Type1 -> Type2 -> ... -> TypeN -> TypeName`, and there is special syntactic sugar for lists so that what would normally have to be something like `List Float` to instead be `[Float]`.

So `data Vector = Vector [Float]` creates a function `Vector :: [Float] -> Vector` (note that the function and the result type are different things that happen to share a name).

The `Vector` function is called a type constructor, and type constructors are the only functions that can have initial capital letters in their name.

Comment: I disagree with your last sentence. The `Vector` function is a *data* constructor, not a type constructor. The term "type constructor" as I understand it, is an informal term for a type which takes one or more other types as a parameter to form a "concrete type" (one that has values), eg something like `Maybe` or `IO`. (This usage is backed up by the [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor) amongst other places.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond A type constructor takes *zero* or more arguments; arity and constructor-ness are orthogonal concepts. Type constructors are those types that are defined by `data` (and `newtype`) declarations -- e.g. `Maybe` and `IO` as you say, but also `Bool`, which takes no arguments. Contrast `Either Int`, which takes an argument but is not a constructor or the `f` in `Foldable f`, which takes an argument but is a variable (and so not a constructor).

Comment: @RobinZigmond By analogy: `div` is not a data constructor even though it takes an argument; `True` is a data constructor even though it doesn't.

Comment: @DanielWagner OK, I see what you mean, although I think it's largely personal preference as most of these terms aren't (afaik) officially designed in the language spec. Your usage of "type constructor" seems no different from what would normally be called simply a "type" (when that's not used as a synonym for "concrete type"). In any case, my purpose was not to split hairs over terminological definitions but just to point out something defined in this answer that goes against what is found in many sources.

Comment: @RobinZigmond If I were not using "type" to mean "concrete type", then I would consider both `Maybe` and `Either Int` to be types, but only one the first is a type constructor. The Report officially designates things this way [in the chapter on user-defined data types](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-680004.2).

Comment: thanks @DanielWagner, that settles it and I stand corrected. I hadn't realised these terms were defined in the Report (and yes I was too lazy to check :/ )